# "Data source name not found" when adding linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, linked-server, pervasive-sql

I am trying to add a linked server to a sql server 2012 database using ssms 2012.

the linked server is pervasive sql. here's how i am trying to do it:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 
   @server = 'kslap208', 
   @provider = 'MSDASQL', 
   @datasrc = 'C003',
   @srvproduct = 'Pervasive'
GO
```

however when i test the connection i am getting this error msg:

[image]

what am i doing wrong? how can i link to an instance of a pervasive sql database?

here is some additional information regarding the DSN to which I am trying to connect:

[image]

Comment: There are two [common reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+data+source+name+not+found) for this error: the DSN is a user DSN but should be a system one; or the DSN is 32-bit but should be 64-bit (or vice versa). I suggest you check those points and if they don't help then please give additional information about the DSN and if you have tested it successfully outside SQL Server. And if possible please do not post error messages as images: they are not searchable.

Comment: @Pondlife thanks so much for your comment! i've confirmed that it's a system DSN and it's 64 bit, i've updated the question with additional info

Comment: Your DSN is called `C003` but your code calls it `kslap208`. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx) explains what each parameter is if you're not sure.

Comment: @Pondlife thank you for catching that. i've updated

Comment: @Pondlife how else would you recommend exploring this?

Comment: It looks like you need to restart the server. I have seen it before: when you just install the ODBC drivers, the services just do not see them. You can first try to restart the service, but most likely you will have to restart the whole server

Comment: @cha, thank you which services would i restart?

Comment: SQL Server (and SQL Server Agent, if you do it in a job)

Comment: do you think i woul dneed to restart even if it's a VM sql server 2012?

Comment: thank you for your help unfortunately it did not work

Comment: Your more recent questions suggest that you did make it work in the end. If so, please consider answering your own question with your solution, to help other people who may have the same problem.

Comment: its some sort of funny memory issue or something. when i select more than a certain number of columns, i get the catastrophic error, otherwise it works